# Flutter :: My Refactor Button does not appear while Right Click on VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, refactoring, right-click

My Refactor Button does not appear while Right Click on VSCode
Flutter: 1.22.5
VSCode: 1.53.0

Is there anyone can help to tell how to make refactor to be appear while Right Click on VSCode?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the Dart LSP server that prevented this from showing up. It's been fixed, but the fix has not reached Dart/Flutter stable channels yet:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2885

You can still access all of the refactors from the Lightbulb menu (`Ctrl`+`.`) in the meantime, or you could disable the "Dart: LSP Preview" setting in VS Code to revert to the older protocol until the fix has rolled out.

Comment: Thanks for your solution & advises. My refactor menu already back. I do your suggestion to disable the "Dart: LSP Preview" setting in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

You can use refactor command Ctrl+Shift+R in VS code